# Projecting single pointGeometry object with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system

In an attempt to create a python add-in for ArcMap that will pass x and y coordinates to another application via a mouse click on the map, I have written the following code.  I need the output coordinates to be in WGS_1984 and therefore have to project a geometry object.  The problem I'm running into is that whenever the script executes the projectAs() method I get the following error.  Code at bottom

[image]

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins
import webbrowser
import os, sys
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

class ToolClass2(object):
    """Implementation for StreetView_addin.tool (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.shape = "NONE" # Can set to "Line", "Circle" or "Rectangle" for interactive shape drawing and to activate the onLine/Polygon/Circle event sinks.

    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
        sr_df = df.spatialReference
        xValue = x
        yValue = y
        pointList = [[xValue, yValue]]
        point = arcpy.Point()
        for pt in pointList:
            point.X = pt[0]
            point.Y = pt[1]

            pointGeometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(point, sr_df)
            pointGeometry.projectAs("WGS 1984")

            centroid = str(pointGeometry.centroid)
            centList = centroid.split(" ")
            xValue2 = centList[0]
            yValue2 = centList[1]
```

I have tried adding the optional transformation for the projectAs() method as well without success.  What am I missing here?

Comment: The problem would appear to be that the point has no spatial reference to start from try pointGeometry=arcpy.PointGeometry(point,df.spatialReference) before .projectAs. The rest of the code looks fine but doesn't appear to do much, I assume you're exporting xValue2 and yValue2 to a file or using them in some other way..

Comment: @Michael Miles-Stimson The sr_def object contains the original spatial ref via the 3rd and 4th lines.  You have assumed correctly, this is only a portion of what I'm doing, xValue2 and yValue2, are going to be used by another portion of the script once I can get them right.  I suppose another way to ask the same thing would be... How do I make the centroid property return the Decimal Degree equivalent in "WGS 1984"?

Comment: Your code is mostly right but you're destroying the spatial reference by taking it out to a string and replacing underscores, supply the spatial reference as an object derived from the data frame.

Comment: That makes sense, and it now works except when I try to return the centroid it is still the original x, and y values.  I'll update the code to show where it's at now.  Thanks

Comment: What's the data frame's / input coordinate system?

Comment: If that's working GeoJohn perhaps put that in as an answer. @mkennedy - it (mostly) doesn't matter, you get it as an object. You will get errors if the data frame has no coordinate system defined (but that usually defaults to assumed geographic or NAD) or the transformation isn't populated. All that's important is to set the spatial reference of the point to the spatial reference of the data frame then call projectAs to project to geographic.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I was wondering if the input SR was also a GCS, particularly NAD83 or ETRS89 which could be why there's no change in the centroid values.

Comment: The input is a projected system.  NAD 1927 StatePlane New Mexico East FIPS 3001.  However, the tool, in theory, should be able to work with any input system.

Comment: So...  Maybe I have this all wrong...  What I want is to be able to click the map in FIPS 3001 and return the Decimal Degree equivalent even if the map units are feet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@GeoJohn: I don't know if you've solved this, but the result of the `pointGeometry.projectAs("WGS 1984")` needs to be assigned to a result variable (e.g., `projectedPointGeometry = pointGeometry.projectAs("WGS 1984")`). The original `pointGeometry` is unchanged by the `projectAs` method. The result variable should have the location in decimal degrees. I need to do a similar thing, and was able to figure it out based on your code, so thank you for posting this question.

Comment: Wow!  No, I never solved this.  What a simple oversight.  I sort of gave up on this project since it was just something I was trying to implement for my own use.  Thanks for your answer!  I can probably finish this now!

Comment: The code helped me as well!

Answer (score 5):

for transforming form Swiss-LV95 to WGS84 I currently use

```
arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(swissX,swissY),arcpy.SpatialReference(2056)).projectAs(arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))
```

with ArcGIS 10.1