# Using ArcPy, I can't panToExtent to intended area using Decimal Degree coordinate

Tags: arcpy, extents, mxd

I'm trying to programmatically pan to a coordinate before I export a map and I've started off by using Identify to get a test coordinate in Decimal Degrees:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
x = 30.317459
y = -97.694778

extent = arcpy.Extent(x, y, x, y)
df.panToExtent(extent)

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

When it pans I then use Identify again to check the coordinate and it's in a completely different region. I only have one layer in this mxd and it is in UTM Zone 14 along with the Data Frame.

Comment: Isn't y=-97 "south" of the South Pole?

Comment: Using Go To XY, Long: -97.694778 Lat: 30.317459 puts me in Austin, TX. I've found that no matter what I assign to x or y it takes me to that spot which is the center of the projection (near the Galapagos Islands).

Comment: You're passing coordinates in **meters** to the panToExtent.  It is not expecting Lat/Long, so when it pans it is correctly panning to 30m west and 97m south of your origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing coordinates in **meters** to the panToExtent. It is not expecting Lat/Long, so when it pans it is correctly panning to 30m east and 97m south of your origin.

This modification to your code will temporarily change your data frame's spatial reference, pan to your Lat/Lon, and change back.  Note: I am unsure on the effect this may have on any Transformations or other layers in your data frame.

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

# Get the current Spatial Reference of the Dataframe
currentSR = df.spatialReference 

# Set a temp Spatial Reference (4326 = WGS84)
# This can be changed to relevant spatial reference using PRJ file,
# name of Spatial Reference, or using the coordinate system's 
# factory code (or authority code) 
tempSR = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

# Set the dataframe Spatial Reference to tempSR
df.spatialReference = tempSR  

# Set Extent and Pan to
LatDD = 30.317459
LonDD = -97.694778
extent = arcpy.Extent(LonDD, LatDD, LonDD, LatDD) 
df.panToExtent(extent) 

# Change Dataframe Spatial Reference back
df.spatialReference = currentSR 
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: I did get some performance issues when testing this code, however I believe this is because I don't use UTM Zone 14 or WGS84 (have no data for either), so is probably because I was trying to project Esri basemaps

Comment: You are correct! I'm just not sure why exactly. Why does UTM interpret the values as meters and WGS84 as coordinates? And why does this not make any difference when using the Go To XY tool? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

For panToExtent use the coordinates of your data frames coodinate system. As you said and Midavalo explained, the Point x = 30.317459, y = -97.694778 is measured in meters.  So if you want to use geographic locations, change the coordinate sytem of your data frame or project the geographic coordinates into your UTM-Zone. For the last, it is discussed here:
[How do you project a single pointGeometry object with arcpy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137700/how-do-you-project-a-single-pointgeometry-object-with-arcpy)
Be aware that you mixed up x and y, x should be "lon" and y should be "lat"!

Comment: That makes perfect sense, the problem I'm having now is that the arcpy.Extent function only accepts a "number or string" and I don't know how to use my x,y inputs with a new spatial reference. And you're also correct about me mixing up x,y. Much appreciated!

Comment: After projecting a Point use the Points attributes X and Y. So if you have a Point-Object pt you can create an extent with 
    extent = arcpy.Extent(pt.X, pt.Y, pt.X, pt.Y)

Comment: I'm finding that you can only project a point geometry, and I can't use the pt.X/pt.Y methods on the geometry. I would like to use this approach however as it would simplify my code.